# Simple d3.json call fail

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, cors

How can this possibly fail?

```
d3.json("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time",
   function(){
      console.log(arguments);
   });
```

I'm getting The ole' CORS `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, **however**, I can successfully make calls to `https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker` without any issues.

I've spent an embarrassingly amount of time already.

EDIT:

This works for /Ticker:

```
var myurl = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades";
var data = "pair=ETHXBT";
var r = d3.json(myurl).header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(data, function(error, response){console.log(arguments);});
```

This __does not work_ for /Trades (again, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error):

```
var myurl = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades";
var data = "pair=ETHXBT";
var r = d3.json(myurl).header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(data, function(error, response){console.log(arguments);});
```

Here's the Kraken API description: https://www.kraken.com/help/api

So far my biggest conclusion is that I'm stupid, but I need your help to determine just *how* stupid.

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  happens because the origin is different .So browser will block the URL specially in chrome. Use the json in the script it self or run the app inside tomcat.

Comment: Odd thing is it works for /Ticker, but not for the other two. I can't imagine Kraken's web server sending different response headers depending on the requested URI, so I figure the problem is at my end...

Comment: just having a look at this too, and I can see different headers. Ticker return Vary: Origin, Trades does not. This header is used with CORS with CDNs, and the Kraken API seems to be served off cloudfront. I've not worked with this before, so I am not entirely sure how/why this matters.

Comment: Further to the above: I was not looking closely enough, the access-control-allow-origin header is also present on Ticker, but not Trades. Looks like a problem with the Kraken API.

Comment: Somehow that's nice to hear – I thought I was going insane. In that case, guess we're among first trying to access their API through AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

Just got this from Kraken's support team:

> Hi,
>
> Thank you very much for reaching out to us. Only ticker allows CORS. Please let us know if you have any further questions!
>
> Warm Regards,
>
> ...